# Avoid duplicate network requests in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, rest, networking, alamofire

I have an app with an UITabBarViewController or Side menu so I can navigate between two ViewControllers: "Clients" and "Visits".

The viewDidAppear method of ViewController "Clients" and "Visits" make a request to a REST API, the request is the same URL for both ViewControllers, it returns a list of clients with their visits.

If I open the app I appear on ViewController "Clients", then I go to ViewController "Visits" while "Clients" is still making the request, at this point I'm requesting the same data twice.

How can I avoid this? I don't think it's a good idea to make a request while the previous hasn't ended.

The request can be heavy, specially the first time, as later on it saves the data into cache.

What's the appropriate solution for this, and who it can be handled with Alamofire?

Comment: if you are using a manager object for networking with alamofire then you could simply set a "receivingClientsData" Bool property in it and check it before the future request . However, it would still not solve your problem because then you'll have to deal with the second tab, while first call is still being done or you won't let user to jump there which is not a good user experience. In this circumstances, what I would do is loading the Clients during my application startup - since it would be already done and saved into cache, why would it wait - and get rid of unnecessary network calls.